# how to sort by dates in format d-month-y in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, date

I have a column with dates looking like this: 10-apr-18.
when I'm transposing my df or doing anything with it, pandas automatically sort this column by the day (the first number) so it's not chronological.

I've tried to use to_datetime but because the month is a string it won't work.

How can I convert this to date OR cancel the automatically sorting (my raw data is already in the right order).

Comment: If I run this locally, it actually manages to convert this to a datetime object.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest convert to datetimes with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) and parameter `format`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':['10-may-18','10-apr-18']})
#also working for me
#df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%d-%b-%y')

df = df.sort_values('dates')
df['dates'] = df['dates'].dt.strftime('%d-%B-%y')
print (df)
         dates
1  10-April-18
0    10-May-18
```

---

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'dates':['10-may-18','10-apr-18']})
#also working for me
#df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'])
df['datetimes'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%d-%b-%y')

df = df.sort_values('datetimes')

df['full'] = df['datetimes'].dt.strftime('%d-%B-%y')
print (df)
       dates  datetimes         full
1  10-apr-18 2018-04-10  10-April-18
0  10-may-18 2018-05-10    10-May-18
```

Comment: I actually want to keep having the month in it's full name. is it possible?

Comment: @NetaGeva - yes, but if need sorting or processing later, better is datetimes. But if necessary, you can create 2 columns - one with strings and another with datetimes

Comment: You can also transform the date back to whatever format you want after sorting

Answer (score 0):

```
df['dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dates'], format='%d-%b-%y').dt.strftime('%d/%B/%y')
```

Comment: you can tweak the `.dt.strftime('%d/%B/%y')` to get the output you want. However, it will not be a datetime object anymore, it will be just a string.